# Create HTMLResponse with meta

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to create a `response` object with meta data.

```
def parse(self,response):
    if 'some string' in response.url:
        data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, meta=response.meta, body=data['html'].encode("utf8").decode('string_escape'))
```

This gives an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'meta'
```

Any idea how to create a `response` object where I can still call the `response.meta` object as for normal requests?

**Edit:**
As suggested by Umair I've tested this:

```
def parse(self,response):
    if 'some string' in response.url:
        data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        response.replace(body = data['html'].encode("utf8").decode('string_escape'))
```

However, this gives an escaped HTML output. In shell this results as:

```
In [20]: response.replace(body = data['html'].encode("utf8").decode('string_escape'))
Out[20]: <200 https://www.some.url>

In [21]: response.xpath('//ul')
Out[21]: 
[<Selector xpath='//ul' data=u'<ul class=\'\\"results_list\\"\'>           '>,
```

While using `HtmlResponse` I'm getting this result:

```
In [17]: test = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, body=data['html'].encode("utf8").decode('string_escape'))

In [18]: test.xpath('//ul')
Out[18]: 
[<Selector xpath='//ul' data=u'<ul class="results_list">               '>,
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this, keep your original `response` as it is, and replace its `body` with the new one you want.

```
response.replace(body = data['html'].encode("utf8").decode('string_escape'))
```

Comment: This works, but seems to escaping the HTML content. Example of selector:  `<Selector xpath='//ul' data=u'<ul class=\'\\"opening_hours_list\' weekend'>` while the outcome when using `HtmlResponse` gives an output like this: `<Selector xpath='//ul' data=u'<ul class="opening_hours_list weekend"> '>`. I've updated the question to include the outcomes of this.

Comment: Dont you need text only? Just do //text() in your xpath

Comment: I need to be able to select specific elements through xpaths. The escaping prevents me from doing so.

Comment: Maybe try only `data['html'].encode("utf8")` instead of `data['html'].encode("utf8").decode('string_escape')`

Comment: For some reason this gives me exactly the same result.

Comment: xpaths do work, but because the HTML code is escaped, I'm not able to select it properly (without escaping my xpaths)